# Best way to clean up axis labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a large dataset using Python and matplotlib. I'm not sure how to make the axis labels less of a mess. I've tried using set_xticks to set them at specific intervals, but that doesn't seem to work, either all the ticks will be on top of each other, there will just be one tick with a seemingly random value, or there will be the correct number of ticks but they all have the same value.

`plt.plot(x, y)`

x and y are lists with a few hundred entries.

[ugly plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uhm6.png)

What's the best way to add good tick labels?

Comment: Sample data for `x` and `y` would be helpful.

Comment: Your x and y values probably contain strings instead of numbers